# Is GitHub Desktop available on Ubuntu?

Tags: software-installation, github

I tried the recently launched GitHub for Windows App. Its pretty cool.

I just wanted to try it on Ubuntu too. Even if it cant do most things its fine, I just want to try it out.

But I'm unable to install the app using Wine. It opens the Wine Browser, and then nothing happens. :(

Has anyone done it? Or can anyone tell me how to do use GitHub Desktop in Ubuntu?

Comment: Others have told your about the GitHub App. But I encourage you to try GitCola, which is also another awesome Git GUI for Linux.

Comment: It is now available for Ubuntu as a native package

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could just download the installer and see if it works.

but you can also install the command line version of git, so you are not restricted to github, and since you can paste the url into terminal, there isnt a real problem.

But whatever floats your boat m8.

I will try to install it now for you, give me 5 minutes

edit:

Doesnt seem to be working, he opens it in a bowser or something.

No it doesnt work.

Comment: I use Git on Ubuntu, but I just wanted to try it GitHub's App... Thanks a lot for installing and trying it yourself. :D

Answer (score 3):

Currently, Github Desktop for GNU/Linux is not officially supported by GitHub, but there is a fork which hosts a version for Ubuntu.

Add the the package repository to your system.

```
 sudo wget -qO - https://packagecloud.io/shiftkey/desktop/gpgkey | sudo apt-key add -

 sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://packagecloud.io/shiftkey/desktop/any/ any main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/packagecloud-shiftky-desktop.list'

 sudo apt-get update

 sudo apt install github-desktop
```

Or you can directly grab the .deb package from https://github.com/shiftkey/desktop/releases

Comment: @Archisman Panigrahi Thank you, sir for your editing :)

Answer (score 1):

It is not present yet in http://appdb.winehq.org/, so I think it indeed doesn't work, and I would suggest to add the application there and share your experience.

Wine is like a lottery with new software.