# WineHQ + GitHub Desktop on Ubuntu?

Tags: wine, github

I'm fairly new to Ubuntu and I cant seem to find a way to run GitHub Desktop Client on Ubuntu. Is there anyway to do it with WineHQ? Any experience with it?

Comment: Or use one of these 15 alternatives https://alternativeto.net/software/github-desktop/?platform=linux   "Any experience with it?" Wine should be avoided at ll cost. Why not virtualbox+windows? That would make it a native install of github

Comment: @Rinzwind Will GitKraken not limit the functions or anything? I find VM + Windows to be too much of an efford/resource consuming task..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is GitHub Desktop available on Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/143388/is-github-desktop-available-on-ubuntu)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a workaround USE THE PREVIOUS VERSION:

To install the previous version (which works and tested bionic ubuntu 18.04 LTS/19.10 eoan/20.04 focal) remove the version you tried to install then do the below (from terminal):

Updated July 2021 for github desktop 2.6.

```
sudo wget https://github.com/shiftkey/desktop/releases/download/release-2.6.3-linux1/GitHubDesktop-linux-2.6.3-linux1.deb
### Uncomment below line if you have not installed gdebi-core before
# sudo apt-get install gdebi-core 
sudo gdebi GitHubDesktop-linux-2.6.3-linux1.deb
```

Comment: Great fix! Works great with Ubuntu 19.10 - However, I'm sticking to GitKraken since it's the more choice stable for Linux.